# Using styleguidist in a react native application

Tags: react-native, uglifyjs, react-styleguidist

I'm trying to use styleguidist in a react native application application;

I come across this link and implemented the exact same set up in my application:

https://github.com/styleguidist/react-styleguidist/tree/master/examples/react-native

After running npx styleguidist build, i got this output:

**FAIL  Failed to compile
build/bundle.f44bbfd4.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token punc «:», expected punc «,» [build/bundle.f44bbfd4.js:372,1165]**

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more examples of what exact code changes you made and to what files? I had a similar issue and it turned out I was applying config changes to webpack.config.js that needed to go into the styleguide.config.js instead.